# Difference between class Book.all and an array of books

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I ve got a class named Book with a method `self.to_csv` . 
This works:

```
books = Book.all 
books.to_csv
```

But if i have an array of books, it won t. The question is how can I get the same result with an array?

```
Book.all = [Book1,Book2]
myArray = [Book1,Book2]
```

What s the difference?

Comment: You've got a typo in the array code block. I don't believe your intention is `Book.all = [Book1,Book2]`. Shouldn't that be `myArray = [Book1, Book2]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The question is how can I get the same result with an array*:

```
Book.where(id: [Book1, Book2]).class
#  Book::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

The thing is, how you define `to_csv`. If it's at a class level (meaning, a class method within the Book model) you'll have access to it when invoking it in a `Post::ActiveRecord_Relation` book as it works through ActiveRecord delegation:

```
Book.all.respond_to?(:to_csv)
# true

Book.all.method(:to_csv).source_location
# ["/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb", 64] # or similar
```

While an array of books is just that, an array of books. And if you haven't touched the Array class, there won't be a `to_csv` method:

```
[Book1, Book2].class
# Array

[Book1, Book2].respond_to?(:to_csv)
# false
```

Hence, no method definition:

```
[Book1, Book2].method(:to_csv).source_location
# NameError: undefined method `to_csv' for class `Array'
# Did you mean?  to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails the `.all` method returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object.
While this object type has some similarities as `Array`, such as methods inherited by `Enumerable`, the object is not an actual instance of `Array` class.

The short answer is that you really can't and probably should not expect an instance of `Array` to behave like an instance of `ActiveRecord_Relation`.

But what you may really be trying to do is this:

```
books = Book.where(id: [Book1.id, Book2.id])
```

This WILL return an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object. So now you should be able to do

```
books.to_csv
```

Perhaps do some reading on

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html